# Switching the content of an HTML-element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, addeventlistener

I just tried a DOM-Manipulation exercise, which I cannot complete. To goal would be to switch the content of a given paragraph back and forth by clicking the same button. I get until the point to change the content of the paragraph as well as that of the button but not anything further.

It tried it this way:

```
document.querySelector('#even').addEventListener('click', changeEven);

function changeEven() {
    let even = document.querySelectorAll('p:nth-child(even)');
    let evenBtn = document.querySelector('#even');

    if (evenBtn.innerHTML.indexOf('even' >= 0)) {
        for (var i = 0; i < even.length; i++) {
            evenBtn.innerHTML = 'Change paragraph text to normal';
            even[i].innerHTML = 'This is an even paragraph.';
        };
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < even.length; i++) {
            evenBtn.innerHTML = 'Change paragraph text to even';
            even[i].innerHTML = 'This is a paragraph.';
        }
    };
};
```

The first half seems to function, as it changes the content of the paragraphs, but if I want to switch it back, it fails to respond.

Thanks for any insights in response.

Comment: The assignment to `evenBtn.innerHTML` doesn't need to be in the loops.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Typo: `>= 0` should not be inside the parentheses of `indexOf()`

Comment: `if (evenBtn.innerHTML.indexOf('even') >= 0)`. Even better, use `evenBtn.innerHTML.includes('even')`